# Error writing to file C:\Config.Msi\..." Windows 7 install of Vagrant 1.7.1 or 1.6.5

Tags: windows-7, installation, windows-installer, vagrant

On Windows 7 while installing Vagrant 1.7.1 from the msi file, I get the error: "Error writing to file C:\Config.Msi..."

I read a few suggestions for this general kind of issue and tried:

- re-registering msiexec.exe
- `isacl icacls "C:\Config.Msi" /T /C /grant administrators:F`

Other programs install OK. I previously had Vagrant 1.3.7 installed but I have uninstalled it.

Comment: Why are you installing Vagrant in the root directory?  You are having permissions problems for that reason.

Comment: It's not the case. I am installing Vagrant in the default location using the intstaller. That is C:\HashiCorp\vagrant. I have got past my problem and will post an answer later today with my findings.

Comment: You could try [my answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/1123101/how-do-i-fix-a-corrupted-itunes-installation-on-windows-7/1291456#1291456) and see if it works for you.